# Firebase Google Sign in Crash Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

```
@IBAction func GoogleLoginDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Google login completed")
    try? GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
   try? GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    try? GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
  try?  auth(authentication: user.authentication)

}
func auth(authentication: GIDAuthentication)
{
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken , accessToken: authentication.accessToken)


    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        else
        {


            print(user?.email)

            print(user?.displayName)

            x = true
            name = (user?.displayName)!
            self.movespecial()
        }

    })
}
```

I can login, but when the google window opens and if I hit the done the app crashes. Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

I have been working on this app for a while and this is the final step.
The error I get is

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Where is error?

Comment: @javimuu  The Error I get is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Looking at the error that is being returned, it seems that is ocurring at `name = (user?.displayName)!`, for some unknown reason the user is returning `nil` or it doesn't have a `displayName` property. It can also be due to your Firebase configuration.

Comment: @AlexandreLara what should i do to my firebase config its not the user displayname

Comment: I believe that the first thing that you should do is check if `user`is nil, you can use a `guard let` expression to do that, for instance: `guard let myUser = user else { print("user is nil") return}`. If the user is not nil, try going to your Firebase account and download a new `google-services.json` file and put it in your project. In the Authentication section, check if the sign-in provider that you are using, is enabled.

Comment: @AlexandreLara   I can login, but when the google window opens and if i hit the done button the app crashes

Comment: Try setting the delegate before calling signin.

Comment: @chengsam I will try that thanks

Comment: @chengsam it did not work

Comment: Did you put breakpoints to see which line of code crashes?

Comment: Yes, but they don't execute

Comment: Can you enter the `auth(authentication: GIDAuthentication)` function?

Comment: Let me try that one second

Comment: Thread 1 exc bad instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if error == nil
    {
        auth(authentication: user.authentication)
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```